# iOS google drive api archive build error

Tags: ios, google-drive-api

I am currently working with google drive sdk for iOS. I just tested it on the simulator and everything worked good. I logged it I retrieved files and folders, but when I tried to archive I got this error:

```
Ld /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName normal armv7
    cd /Users/mac/Documents/Projects/MyProjectName
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 6.0
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk -L/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/mac/Documents/Projects/MyProjectName/MyProjectName -F/Users/mac/Documents/Projects/MyProjectName/MyProjectName/Third\ Libraries -filelist /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework ImageIO -framework MessageUI -framework QuartzCore -framework UIKit -all_load -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -lGTLTouchStaticLib -framework QuartzCore -framework MobileCoreServices -framework SystemConfiguration -framework Security -framework DropboxSDK -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProjectName-dtjsurmhdxhcktaoufqjodibkpdd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyProjectName/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyProjectName.build/Release-iphoneos/MyProjectName.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MyProjectName

ld: library not found for -lGTLTouchStaticLib
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Did you get any solution afterwards? Am facing the same problem

Comment: @ManiacOne Hi, I have create repo, where I will add some features using dropbox and google drive api, you can check and download it here https://github.com/matrosovDev/SimpleClouds/wiki/How-to-setup I  just started, so right now you can just find how to make initial setup, but in future I will add all features like login, download, upload files etc

Comment: @ManiacOne let me know if some questions with repo

Comment: i dont have prob in login, download or upload. My work was with share links and I have done that successfully. It also runs in device perfectly. However whenever am creating an archive I am getting problems. Its creating a Generic Xcode Archive, so no .ipa.

Comment: I have seen You have just started making a repo. Thanks for your support.

Comment: ok try to replace your google drive sdk with mine